# Is there any way to select a "best shot" from a smart sequence following windows phone 8.1 update 1 (denim)

Tags: camera, lumia-denim-update, nokia-lumia-930

I have a nokia lumia 930 and have a number of "smart sequence" photos that I still need to pick the "best shot" for.

My phone upgraded yesterday to "denim" and it seems that the smart sequence feature has been done away with and replaced by a 4k video frame capture feature.

I would sill like to go through the existing smart sequence photo's on my phone and pick the best shot but there doesnt seem to be an option anywhere?

I've already found and tried with lumia camera classic and cannot find the option in there either.